# ArrayList optimization memory

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, bitmap

Hello guys I have a question :

Is it better for memory, to create and manipulate an ArrayList of Bitmap , or create and manipulate an ArrayList of File , which contains files and create a Bitmap with each file path ?

For me I prefer to have an ArrayList of File and create every bitmap when I need to, using Glide.

I really want to know how to optimize bitmaps managing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously:

- If the String needs more memory than the bitmap it is better to have a List of bitmaps
- If the bitmap needs more memory than the string it is better to have a List of Strings.

So if you are manipulating icons, a String can be potentially bigger than the bitmap, but generally a path to the bitmap saved as String is much more smaller than a bitmap.

If their size is similar in dimension use the one that is easier to adopt in your code.